# What can be said about the free-forgetful adjunction of monad algebras with respect to topoi?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, adjoint-functors

For a monad T on a topos E, if T has a right adjoint, then the Eilenberg-Moore category of algebras of T is equivalent to the co-Eilenberg-Moore category of co-algebras for the right adjoint comonad and thus a topos because the right adjoint will be left exact.

The cofree-forgetful adjunction of a left exact comonad is a geometric morphism, Cofree, $\mathit{E} \rightarrow \mathit{T\mbox{-}Coalg}$.
What can we say about the free-forgetful adjunction arising for the monad with a right adjoint?
Here one might hazard a guess that $\mathit{Forget}$ will be a geometric morphism, but for that we would need the $\mathit{Free}$ functor to preserve finite limits. Does it? Or is $Forget$ a logical functor, given it is a right adjoint and thus preserves limits, does it also preserve power objects?

The question can be said compactly follows: Is $\mathit{Forget}$ a geometric morphism? Is either $\mathit{Forget}$ or $\mathit{Free}$ a logical morphism? Or are they some other special morphism of topoi?

Were the properties of the free-forgetful adjunction with respect to the topos structure explicitly stated somewhere in the literature?